# Is there a standard way to link to an external website?

Tags: html, hyperlink, xhtml, href

I was taught to do:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a>
```

as opposed to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

Is this still the standard way to do it?  I was told that it helps the use to identify that they will be leaving the site so that's why you should include the full URL.

Comment: You got some horribly bad advice. That hasn't ever been the "standard".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

If it is important to inform the user he is leaving the site you can do what Wikipedia does and put an image next the link, like:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

No, and it never has been.

Browsers include mechanisms to tell people where a link will take them. Having human readable link text is much more important.

Comment: Good tip on the browser.  I'm unclear on the meaning of "human readable link text".  Do you recommend he use the full http path or just have text to show a link as opposed to say...an image?

Comment: Have content designed for human consumption, which is usually text, but could be an image. Don't show URLs to people, they are designed (primarily) for machine consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The only time a URL should be shown in the link text is if a user entered a URL as some type of submission data and the URL text was made into a link (a la Twitter, where posting a URL makes it a link). Otherwise, URLs are generally confusing and scare some users from clicking on them.

Oftentimes, users will be hesitant to click on links where the text is a URL, as the text could say one thing and the link itself could go somewhere else. This is how a lot of phishing scams work, and consumers are starting to catch on.

Answer (score 0):

Almost no one writes the full URL on the link. for example, look at google search results, or any other web page.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are making a website for real people, reading real text (and lets assume people are more important than world wide web network, which then is more important than giant searchengines etc etc)

Then, when writing a paragraph, it ould be helpfull to include readable text, as opposed to full url, unless you want to just link to the main root of a website, but often you link to a specific page, with a specific content... Example right out of my fantasy.

> On our vacation we visited the [Buenos
>   Aires Hotel](http://#) which had a splendid view
>   on the [Boulevar Des Magnifiques](http://#), a
>   tropical double laned walking street
>   overviwing the sea on the Cliff
>   Savage de Sollei. I will never forget the fish we ate at the [Risotto
>   Restaurant](http://#). It came close to my [first kiss](http://#) which I gave in our
>   [holiday in Egypt](http://#) to my current husband.

Now read the above text again, but insted put there the full urls, see my point?

- Care about your audience / real people more than
- caring about rules especially machine-rules

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on our reader. Example I printed out some information on website.

1. Please click **[here](http://www.howstuffworks.com/)**  to see how it works!
2. Please visit **http://www.howstuffworks.com/** to see how it works!

No **2** is more standard

Comment: Disagree; "Please visit [howstuffworks.com](http://www.howstuffworks.com)" or "Please visit [How Stuff Works](http://www.howstuffworks.com)" are both far better options than your #2.